# Setting a data from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a ListFragment and I want to edit item when clicked in List View.

I am using this method.

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        if(dbHelper != null){
            Item item = dbHelper.getProjectRowById(id);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Save.class);
            //Here i want to start the activity and set the data using item.  
        }           
    }
```

How do i set data in above method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and why didn't it work?

Comment: I have rephrased the question.

Comment: I see, and your `Save` activity has an `EditText` or some way of editing the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send extra data along with an Intent when you start a new Activity.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(dbHelper != null){
        Item item = dbHelper.getProjectRowById(id);

        // Put the data on your intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Save.class);
        // If Item implements Serializable or Parcelable, you can just send the item:
        intent.putExtra("dataToEdit", item);
        // Otherwise, send the relevant bit:
        intent.putExtra("data1", item.getSomeDataItem());
        intent.putExtra("data2", item.getAnotherDataItem());
        // Or, send the id and look up the item to edit in the other activity.
        intent.putExtra("id", id);

        // Start your edit activity with the intent.
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In the edit activity, you can get the Intent that started it.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(...);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("dataToEdit")) {
        Item item = (Item) intent.getSerializableExtra("dataToEdit");
        if (item != null) {
            // find edittext, and set text to the data that needs editing
        }
    }

}
```

Then the user can edit that text, and you can save it to the database when they click save or whatever. Then call `finish` on your save activity.

If you need to send the saved data back to the original activity (instead of, say, just requerying in `onStart`), look into [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). If you use that, you can set a result code with [`setResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) before calling `finish`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(dbHelper != null){
        //don't do this here Item item = dbHelper.getProjectRowById(id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Save.class);
        intent.putExtra("MyItemId", id);
    }           
}
```

In your second activity, you get the Id and load the element with

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
long id = extras.getInt("MyItemId");
Item item = dbHelper.getProjectRowById(id);
```

Your need dbHelper there, too. If you want only one instance of it, make it a variable of your App class.